# Is there an angularjs nested table element limit?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to render HTML that looks like this with angular:

```
  <table>
  ...
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><b>title</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="3">detail</td>
        </tr>
```

There is a detail line for each item.

My data looks like this:

```
$scope.Data = {
  ItemList: [{
    "Name": "Bubba",
    "List": [
      {
        item1: 7,
        item2: 3,
        item3: 4,
        comment: "comment 1 "
      },
      {
        item1: 7,
        item2: 3,
        item3: 4,
        comment: "comment 2 "
      },
      {
        item1: 7,
        item2: 3,
        item3: 4,
        comment: "comment 3 "
      }]
        }, {
    "Name": "Bubba2",
    "List": [{
        item1: 7,
        item2: 3,
        item3: 4,
        comment: "comment 4 "
      },
      {
        item1: 7,
        item2: 3,
        item3: 4,
        comment: "comment 5 "
      },
      {
        item1: 7,
        item2: 3,
        item3: 4,
        comment: "comment 6 "
      }]
  }];
}
```

Here is template I have been using:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>header</td>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="j in Data.ItemList">
            <td colspan="4"><b>{{j.Name}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="k in j.List">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>{{k.item1}}</td>
            <td>{{k.item2}}</td>
            <td>{{k.item3}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="3">{{k.comment}}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

It does not render the comment because it is outside the looping tr.

Is it possible to do this? I have tried a few thing but nothing seems to work.

Here is a plunker of where I am with this: http://plnkr.co/edit/7YtEX1?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.2 has a new directive called `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` which should allow what you're attempting. [See documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat#description).

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="j in Data.ItemList">
        <td colspan="4"><b>{{j.Name}}</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="k in j.List">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{k.item1}}</td>
        <td>{{k.item2}}</td>
        <td>{{k.item3}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3">{{k.comment}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, it seems like you're trying to use tables to achieve a particular layout of non-tabular data. If I were in your shoes, I would use some other HTML markup.